# Spring @PreAuthorize passes null to Service

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have an issue with **@PreAuthorize** and a sevice that checks if the athenticated user may access the searched item.

The one service *callDistributionRequest* that gets the item is working fine - **@PreAuthorize** recieves and passes the right *distId*. The other one *updateDistributionRequestExportFileName* gets also the right *distId* and passes it to the *distributionRequestService*. On the method *userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest* distId comes as a **null**

The Spring RestController with the two web services

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class DistributionRequestRESTController {

    @Autowired
    private @Getter @Setter DistributionRequestService distributionRequestService;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private String logResponse = " - response: ";

    @Autowired
    public DistributionRequestRESTController(DistributionRequestService distributionRequestService) {
        this.distributionRequestService = distributionRequestService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = Consts.URLDISTRIBUTIONREQUEST + Consts.URLDISTREQID)
    public DistributionRequest callDistributionRequest(@PathVariable long distId) {

        String loginfo = "get distribution with id: " + distId;
        //log.info(loginfo);

        DistributionRequest found = distributionRequestService.findOne(distId);

        log.info(loginfo + logResponse + JSONParser.toJsonString(found));

        return found;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = Consts.URLDISTRIBUTIONREQUEST + Consts.URLDISTREQID + Consts.URLUPDATE + Consts.URLFILENAME)
    public DistributionRequest updateDistributionRequestExportFileName(
            @PathVariable long distId,
            @RequestBody String fileName,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user) {

        String loginfo = user.getUsername() + " try to update filename with : " + fileName;
        //log.info(loginfo);

        DistributionRequest updated =
                distributionRequestService.updateExportFilename(distId, fileName);

        log.info(loginfo + logResponse + JSONParser.toJsonString(updated));

        return updated;
    }

}
```

The Service interface:

```
public interface DistributionRequestService {

    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority('USER', 'ADMIN') and @distributionRequestOwnerService.userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(#distId)")
    DistributionRequest findOne(Long distId);

    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority('USER', 'ADMIN') and @distributionRequestOwnerService.userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(#distId)")
    DistributionRequest updateExportFilename(Long distId, String filename);
}
```

And the class that checks if the user may access the searched item

```
@Service(value = "distributionRequestOwnerService")
public class DistributionRequestOwnerServiceImpl implements DistributionRequestOwnerService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private DistributionRequestsRepository distributionRequestsRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(Long distId) {
        return userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(distId, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(Long distributionRequestId, String username) {
        DistributionRequest distributionRequest = distributionRequestsRepository.findOne(distributionRequestId);

        ServiceAccount currentUser;
        if (username == null)
            currentUser = accountService.getCurrentUser();
        else
            currentUser = accountService.findByUsername(username);

        if (distributionRequest != null
                && distributionRequest.getRecipientId() == currentUser.getRecipientId())
            return true;

        throw new AercacheWSException(Consts.EXCEPTIONMISSINGELEMENTORPERMITION);
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [duplicate to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357607/1352040)

as @teppic pointed parameter in interfaces should be annotated.

```
public interface DistributionRequestService {

    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority('USER', 'ADMIN') and @distributionRequestOwnerService.userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(#distId)")
    DistributionRequest findOne(@Param("distId") Long distId);

    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority('USER', 'ADMIN') and @distributionRequestOwnerService.userBelongsToRecipientOfTheDistributionRequest(#distId)")
    DistributionRequest updateExportFilename(@Param("distId") Long distId, String filename);
}
```