# @PathVariable annotation works different with proxy based on Interface/Class

Tags: java, spring, proxy, annotations

I have interface `UserController` and class `UserControllerImpl`.
When I add `@RequestMapping` and `@PathVariable` in `UserControllerImpl` and I am using proxy based on class I am able to get user using this URL:

GET: `http://localhost:8080/company-control/users/25`

When I change proxy to based on interface and add `@RequestMapping` and `@PatyVariable` to interface I am not able to get it and I receive following error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [int] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.

I am able to solve this issue adding `userId` to `@PathVariable`.

```java
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId);
```

Could someone explain me why I have to add `userId` to `@PathVariable` if I use the same variable name?

Is it connected with proxy?

Comment: Possibly because when someone implements an interface, they can use whatever parameter names they want to (they don't have to match the interface definition).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357607/3591528) has some details, but basically there isn't enough debug info on interfaces for Spring to discover the parameter name by reflection (unless you jump through some hoops).